# Сокет серверный скрипт

Tags: php, сокет

Вопрос возник, не знаю как правильно объяснить... Короче, надумал сделать простой онлайн-сервис, к которому будут подключаться с телефона через сокет. Так вот, как организовать скрипт, который не будет разрывать соединение, а будет общаться с клиентом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходим демон (служба, называйте как хотите). Реализовывается он, как правило, в виде отдельного приложения, а не под управлением веб-сервера (apache и иже с ним), потому что каждое новое подключение будет порождать поток/процесс, который будет обрабатывать запрос от клиента и это будет Вам не подконтрольно (если у Вас конечно не что-нибудь асинхронное). Поэтому то, что предложил [[@Fuzzz3r](/users/2129/fuzzz3r)](/users/2129/fuzzz3r) Вам не подходит.

На чем реализовывать демона, решать Вам, благо средств хватает от скриптовых языков (кстати если вам ближе PHP то можно и на нем написать сервер под PHP-CLI, а может вам приглянется PHPDaemon, node.js, Erlang ...) до C/C++ и ассемблера (хотя тут я наверно загнул :) ).

Comment: @Sh4dow, да, вы правы, я не пробовал ваш подход к управлению php-демонами, но на то у меня свои причины. Привык хранить конфигурацию в файлах(сериализованные массивы, которые уже исправляются через веб-морду, она же и убивает демона, чтобы тот перезапустился с новыми настройками).Да, и скрипт следящий за демоном и перезапускающий его в случае падения больше вселяет доверие чем то что я окажусь рядом с компом и перезапущу его. Вообщем все это разные подходы, местами даже холивары :).

Comment: По поводу утечек памяти, при вашем подходе, угроза вполне реальна, когда демону присылают/отправляют большие объемы данных.

Comment: <pre> $request = ''; $r1 = ''; do { $request .= $r1; $r1 = socket_read($sock, 256); } while ((strlen($r1) > 0) && (strlen($request) < REQUEST_LIMIT)); </pre> Ну и так далее. Я не говорю, что ваш вариант не работает. Ваш вариант требует много знаний вне php + не кроссплатформенный (перенос займет не 5 мин) + вообще-то 10 мин пишется кипер на php же. И да, я форточник ^_^

Comment: Меня linux как серверная платформа больше прельщает, поэтому о кроссплатформенности на данный момент я не задумываюсь. Кипер писать на php - дело вкуса). По поводу вашего цикла - к сожалению он пригоден только для текстовых данных, хотя у него даже с юникодом будут проблемы из-за strlen (юзайте mb_strlen :), все-таки передаваемые данные могут быть любыми в том числе и символами юникода. К сожалению в php неудобно работать с бинарными протоколами, хотя это исправляется за счет небольших надстроек над pack и unpack (ну или написанием собственного расширения для php).

Comment: >> к сожалению он пригоден только для текстовых данных

Нет =) Поток mp3(in/out) проблем не создавал. Текстовые данные - приветствие, дальше что угодно.

>> передаваемые данные могут быть любыми

я кусок алгоритма в общем виде привел, чтоб по-русски не писать) Читаются бинарные данные, а strlen(char(0))=1,поэтому кодировка значения не имеет.

>> неудобно работать с бинарными протоколами

Ересь, я график wav рисовал и на картинки эффекты накладывал (на низком уровне). Другое дело - бинарные данные постоянно кочуют через char/ord, это нагрузку добравляет огромную, тут не спорю)

Comment: @JGDger надеюсь наша с @Sh4dow дискуссия поможет вам в написании вашего сервера :)

Comment: Еще злую шутку с бинарными данными может сыграть параметр `mbstring.func_overload`

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону функций socket_listen, socket_accept. Спокойно работает на php под управлением апача, к слову. Только не на 80 порт сервер ваш вешайте.

В общем случае дело выглядит так:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
error_reporting(0);
$clients = array();
$server = /* создание сокета: create, bind, listen */;
$exit = false;
while (true) {
  if ($exit) break; // при какой-то команде полезно этот флажок менять, иначе довольно трудно вырубить. полезно еще делать if is_file('close.txt') break; для "аварийного" выключения
  if ($client = @socket_accept($server)) {
    /*
       новый клиент.
       читаем входные данные, 
       шлем ответ, 
       добавляем при надобности клиента в список
    */
    }
  foreach ($clients as $client) {
    /* читаем команду, отвечаем */
    }
  sleep(1); // дабы не перегружать сервер
  }
foreach ($clients as $client) 
  @socket_close($client);
@socket_close($server);
```

Comment: работает, то работает, только вот картина интересная будет :) каждый запрос к сайту на котором висит этот скрипт будет пытаться запускать новый сервер. А вот если этот скрипт запустить из консоли (php-cli) - он будет полноценно работать как сервер. Кстати его не придется совсем менять (за исключением первых двух строк). К тому же есть не только ограничение на время работы php скрипта, которое вы выключили, но и на время обработки запроса потоком апача.

Comment: Да, вы танком по воробьям стреляете. Держать апач ради одного скрипта, сервер ради сервера. В то время как строчка `php -f server.php` запустит Ваш скрипт как отдельный процесс.

Comment: Эм, весьма костыльный подход к решению проблемы. Да, удобно издалека(не с рабочего компа) поднять сервер если он упал(единственный плюс, других простите не вижу), но простейший скрипт на баше в цикле, без проблем будет перезапускать Ваши демоны. К тому же нужно убрать ограничение на объем памяти занимаемый скриптом, ибо известный факт - php течет. Давно уже присматриваюсь :))) апач управляет каналом связи с клиентом и потоком/процессом, который запустил интерпретатор php и натравил его на ваш скрипт. Так что убить этот поток ему сил хватит :)

Comment: Ну... например, сервер с асей вполне себе спокойно без аномалий висел месяц) Сервер с записью потока айскаста - неделю. Просто на дольше я их не ставил. Так что я могу только сказать, что вы не пробовали так делать. А наличие POST-формы запуска демона с 15+ настройками перевешивает очень многие минусы) В конце концов, ВПС - ваш сервер и все лимиты памяти/таймауты и прочее вы ставите сами. Проблем с памятью тоже особо не наблюдалось. В общем, это работает, не глючит пр наличии прямых рук, и это - удобно. А так - пробуйте, опровергайте, несколько рабочих проектов ваши тесты не испортят =)

Comment: > `sleep(1); // дабы не перегружать сервер`

Не перегружать сервер - это, конечно, хорошо, но вы понимаете, что ваш демон будет обрабатывать максимум *1 запрос в секунду*?
Советую прочитать вам про [blocking mode][1] и [stream_select()][2]

> `error_reporting(0);`

Так делать нельзя. Никогда.

И потом, я согласен с @GLAGOLA. Запускать демон через apache - это нонсенс.

  [1]: http://php.net/stream-set-blocking
  [2]: http://php.net/stream-select

Comment: >> что ваш демон будет обрабатывать максимум 1 запрос в секунду?

Нет. Я написал **примерный** алгоритм. Вам кто-то мешает поставить socket_select, написать usleep(100) или еще как-то их синхронизировать?

>> Так делать нельзя. Никогда

Не делайте. Я обычно делаю запуск демона в новом окне, а на успешный запуск ставлю `echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>';` Никто, опять же, не отменял перхват и логирование ошибок, а включенный reporting может выкинуть демона (попытка записи в браузер).

>> Запускать демон через apache - это нонсенс.

Не запускайте. Но это работает =)

Comment: > Я написал примерный алгоритм.

И ваш примерный алгоритм способен обработать максимум 1 запрос в секунду.

> написать usleep(100) 

В blocking mode никаких sleep'ов не надо вообще.

> Не делайте.

Проблема в том, что вы даете вредные советы другим. Для того, что бы ошибки не отображались, есть директива display_errors. А для того, что бы демона не выкидывало, используют php-cli, а не апатч.

> Никто, опять же, не отменял перхват и логирование ошибок

Простите, но отключать логирование ошибок, что бы затем перехватывать их логировать уже вручную - это надевать штаны через голову.

Comment: >> максимум 1 запрос в секунду.

Ага, 1 запрос/сек на клиента. Это пример для нон-блока с ручными текстовыми сообщениями, вполне хватает для сотни клиентов. Попробую так - это **абстрактный** алгоритм. Можно поставить блокировку или нет. Можно с задержкой или с socket_select. И еще как угодно. 

>> даете вредные советы другим

Я знаю все его минусы и плюсы. Но вы говорите, что так делать нельзя, а я так делаю и проблем не наблюдаю. "Нонсенс" против "работает" - слабенько. Я повторю: способ "неправильный", но это способ. Но во многих случаях он проще в написании, настройке и  использовании.

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна проблема, в php.ini (файл с настройками php) есть значение max_execution_time, которое накладывает ограничение на время выполнения скрипта по умолчанию ~30 вроде... А это значит, что он будет разрывать соединение... В вашем случае надо обойтись либо без непрерывного соединения, либо без php (заменить на что-либо более подходящее).

Comment: А set_time_limit(0) дело не исправит?

Comment: Исправит, если хостинг разрешает его изменять. Т.е. вам либо с локальной машины его запускать, либо с VDS/VPS/договариваться с хостером.

Comment: Это не проблема. Более того демоны на php запускают через php_cli, который не имеет никаких ограничений по времени по умолчанию.